# System Monitor: can't see anything aside from process name

Tags: 16.04, process, cpu-load, system-monitor

System Monitor is behaving very strangely: `Process Name` takes up the entire width of the app:

[image]

If I uncheck `Process Name` after right clicking, only then can I see everything else...but then I can't see the names of the processes that I'm trying to diagnose.

[image]

What's going on here and can it be fixed?

**INFO**: I'm on a clean install of 16.04.

Comment: Try to play with *Active Processes*, *All Processes*, *My Processes* and *Dependencies*. Which Ubuntu version do you have?

Comment: sorry I have changed my skin and stuff is this `gnome-system-monitor` or a different one .. looks like the one I have sort of :D .. if so you could try `sudo apt-get remove --purge gnome-system-monitor` and make sure its only removing gnome-system-monitor and not anything with it .. i checked mine and it only removes the monitor and nothing else so you can purge it and then `sudo apt-get install gnome-system-monitor` and install it again hopefully fixing the problem

Comment: @N0rbert All of the 'processes' options have the same problem. I'm running Ubuntu 16.04 and have updated my post. @JohnOrion yep, it's the `gnome-system-monitor`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you would move mouse cursor over boundary between columns *Process Name* and *User* you can make left column narrower with `<->` cursor by moving it to the right.

Or check GNOME System Monitor settings with

```
dconf dump /org/gnome/gnome-system-monitor/
```

> (pay attention here for
>    `[proctree]`
>    `col-0-width=...`
>   )

then try to reset all settings of GNOME System Monitor with `dconf` utility (it is located in `dconf-cli` package):

```
dconf reset -f /org/gnome/gnome-system-monitor
```

Comment: Yeah, `col-0-width=3598`. There was no way to resize the column with the mouse (it would resize the entire window). Not sure how that happened but resetting the settings fixed it. Thanks!